# Python decorator not returning a value

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I've been experimenting decorator in python 2.7 and tried setup in idle:

```
def logme(func):
    def wrapped(*args):
        for arg in args: print str(arg)
        func(*args)
    return wrapped

@logme
def my_func(*args):
    res = 1
    for arg in args :
        print "Multiplying %s by %s" % (arg, res)
        res*=arg
    print res
    return res
```

The output is this:

```
2
3 
Multiplying 2 by 1
Multiplying 3 by 2
6
```

So the res value is right. However, when I tried to store the res value via this:

```
x = my_func(2,3)
```

The value of `x` is `None`. Is this correct? If not, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There's no return statement in `wrapped`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to return the result of `func()` in your wrapper:

```
def logme(func):
    def wrapped(*args):
        for arg in args: print str(arg)
        return func(*args)
    return wrapped
```

otherwise `wrapped()` calls `func()` but ignores the returned result.